# How to compare double precision arrays

Tags: postgresql

Simply want to compare double precision column values that return results that are also double precision.

Using PostgreSQL 9.6 I haven't found a way to compare arrays of float or numeric data types without converting them to integers.

```
select * from 
(
    select  
        t1."SubdSec-in-DCA_id",
        t1."float_range" as left_side,
        t2."float_range" as right_side,
        t1."float_range"::numeric[] - t2."float_range"::numeric[] as results
    from "TEST" t1
    cross join lateral (select  "float_range" from "TEST") t2
) t3
order by "SubdSec-in-DCA_id",left_side, right_side
```

`t1."float_range"::int[] & t2."float_range"::int[] as results,`
works: but return values as integers
result: `"T_S07414_DCA4117","{197.598,205.382}","{146.5,146.9}","{198,205}"`

`t1."float_range"::float[] & t2."float_range"::float[] as results,`
fails: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision[] & double precision[]`

`t1."float_range"::numeric[] & t2."float_range"::numeric[] as results`
fails: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric[] & numeric[]`

Comment: There is no simple solution. You'll probably end up writing a function `array_round(double precision[] arr, integer scale)` that rounds every element of the array. This is not going to be fast unless you write the function in C.